# GCC strange std::integral_constant<bool, value> instantiation and compile-time evaluation

Tags: c++, c++17

#### Question context :

While toying with godbolt about ways to recover compile-time contexts using runtime-value,
(yeah, sounds like a bad idea), I found out a context where GCC evaluates `std::integral_constant<bool, value_arg>::value` strangely :

See the complete example on godbolt here : https://godbolt.org/z/KzrK5xz3c

***Disclaimer** : this code is so wrong in many ways, and is for illustration purpose only.*

As you may read, here the `std::integral_constant<bool, value_arg>::value` looks to instantiate the wrong symbols in both cases

```cpp
static_assert(argument_type::value == false); // fail
static_assert(argument_type::value == true);  // also fail !
```

```
<source>:39:44: error: static assertion failed
   39 |         static_assert(argument_type::value == true);
<source>:39:44: note: '(((int)std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value) == 1)' evaluates to false
<source>:38:44: error: static assertion failed
   38 |         static_assert(argument_type::value == false);
<source>:38:44: note: '(((int)std::integral_constant<bool, true>::value) == 0)' evaluates to false
```

However, the runtime check works as expected :

```cpp
if (not (argument_type::value == false))
   throw std::invalid_argument{"unexpected value"};
```

#### **Q** : What point am I missing ?

Thanks for your time, and your love of C++.

#### ***A*** : Use **overload** pattern for context specialisation

https://godbolt.org/z/az5j3YMxz

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

std::visit(overload{
        [](std::integral_constant<bool, false>){
            
        },
        []<typename integral_constant>(integral_constant &&){
           // integral_constant is `std::integral_constant<bool, true>` here  
           // as `std::integral_constant<bool, false>` will fall into the first argument of `overload`

           using argument_type = std::remove_reference_t<integral_constant>;
           static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename argument_type::value_type, bool>);
           static_assert(argument_type::value == true);
    }}, rt_cx::bridge<bool>[false]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the requirements of [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

> [first parameter] - a *Callable* that accepts every possible alternative from every variant

In your case the lambda you pass must accept both `std::integral_constant<bool, false>` and `std::integral_constant<bool, true>`, which is not true because the `static_assert`'s cause the instantiation to be ill-formed.  Having only one of the `static_assert`'s still causes a compilation error ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YjP9fYbT5)).

Having a runtime check such as

```
if (not (argument_type::value == false))
   throw std::invalid_argument{"unexpected value"};
```

is well-formed for all possible alternatives, so you won't get a compilation error.

Comment: I see. In conclusion, my misunderstanding was to think that std::visit only instanciate the matching symbols. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The `static_assert(argument_type::value == true)` is triggered by

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(ijk&&)> [with ijk = std::integral_constant<bool, false>&]':
```

Whereas the `static_assert(argument_type::value == false)` is triggered by

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(ijk&&)> [with ijk = std::integral_constant<bool, true>&]':
```

So I suspect that the point you're missing is that the visiting lambda needs to cope with all the possible types that the `variant` can hold